# Redirect User when they click Menu Option

Tags: php, wordpress

I am setting up a new website where I am managing a small amount of clients. I have created a menu page that when the user is logged out it basically just tells the user to log in. But I want to code for when a user is logged in and clicks on that same menu page, I want it to redirect to a private page I have created for them. Each individual already has a private page. The URL for each private page is "example.com/private-page/username/. If the URL doesn't exist for an individual I just want the code to go back to the original menu page not a nonexistent page.

I have tried different ways including using meta to refresh the page to the other url. I can't figure what exactly isn't working. I am typing the code on the function.php

```
function userredirect(){
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
     if(is_user_logged_in() && is_page('Menu Page')){
         wp_redirect('https://example.com/private-page/'.$current_user->user_login.'/');
     }
}
```

Nothing Happens when I go to the menu page besides it showing the original content for the page. Currently I haven't figured out any clue on how to stop it from redirecting if the webpage doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the redirect is not firing, is because you must exit after a wp_redirect:

See [codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect/)

```
    function get_page_by_slug( $slug ) {
        if( $pages = get_pages() )
            foreach( $pages as $page )
                if( $slug === $page->post_name ) return true;
                return false;
   } 
   function userredirect() {
        global $post;
        if( $post->ID == 999999 ){ /* change number on this line to the post ID you want to redirect from */
            $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
            $slug = $current_user->user_login;
            if( is_user_logged_in() && is_page('Menu Page') ){
                 if( get_page_by_slug($slug) ){
                     wp_redirect('https://example.com/private-page/'.$slug.'/');
                     exit;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    add_action( 'init', 'userredirect' );
```

Comment: So I erased my current code and copied and pasted this code into function.php and again nothing happened when I tested it. Is there anyway I can debug this code? Sorry I am fairly unfamiliar with php.

Comment: @JacobRowe... This should be in your functions.php file, and then you have to call that second function either from the functions file, or from the page that the button first links to. I will update the code to show you how to do it from the functions file.

Comment: @JacobRowe.... try it now... answer updated..... You have to change 999999 to the post ID of whatever page they are first landing on when they click the link.

Answer (score 0):

`is_page('Menu Page')` 
will give true as a result only if user do click on that page. So if he is at any other page wp_redirect function would not start. 
Also for you could wrap your link with function:

```
if get_page_by_path($current_user->user_login) {
#your_link_here
}
```

So your link would be visible only if page exist

Comment: According to his question, they would be on that page, they already clicked the link, went to the page, and now he wants to redirect to another page, if it exists, and if the user is logged in. My answer does this.